# Switching audio to speaker doesn't stay

Tags: swift, bluetooth, avaudiosession, speaker

When I have my airpods connected, switching audio to speaker doesn't stay.This code works in all states except when airpods are connected.

```
var err: Error? = nil
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .voiceChat, options: [.allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP, .mixWithOthers])

        } catch {
            NSLog("Unable to change audio category because : \(String(describing: err?.localizedDescription))")
            err = nil
        }

        try? session.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat)
        if err != nil {
            NSLog("Unable to change audio mode because : \(String(describing: err?.localizedDescription))")
            err = nil
        }
        let sampleRate: Double = 44100.0
        try? session.setPreferredSampleRate(sampleRate)
        if err != nil {
            NSLog("Unable to change preferred sample rate because : \(String(describing: err?.localizedDescription))")
            err = nil
        }
        try? session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.005)
        if err != nil {
            NSLog("Unable to change preferred sample rate because : \(String(describing: err?.localizedDescription))")
            err = nil
        }
```

When UIAlertAction row is selected:

```
  do {
                        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("audioSession error turning off speaker: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
```

Comment: Check out this Q/A, might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922387/unable-to-switch-to-speaker-output-when-bluetooth-headsets-are-connected