# Speaker isn't an available input when airpods are connected

Tags: objective-c, swift, audio, speaker

I am trying to override me application's audio to speaker when the user hits a button but speaker doesn't show as an available audioutput when airpods are connected. What can i do to make the sound go to speaker? This code works when any other bluetooth device is connected.

po AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs

> AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x283dc3410, type = MicrophoneBuiltIn; name = iPhone Microphone; UID = Built-In Microphone; selectedDataSource = (null)>
>     VAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x283dc32b0, type = BluetoothHFP; name = Lindsey’s AirPods; UID = 94:B0:1F:C3:FF:6B-tsco; selectedDataSource = (null)>

```
var err: Error? = nil
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .voiceChat, options: [.allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP, .mixWithOthers])

} catch {
    NSLog("Unable to change audio category because : \(String(describing: err?.localizedDescription))")
    err = nil
}

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("audioSession error turning on speaker: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Please update as to which section is producing the message.

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Maybe this answer can help a bit:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922387/unable-to-switch-to-speaker-output-when-bluetooth-headsets-are-connected